# Adding to min date giving weird result

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a cake order form and as part of it the customer needs to select a day for delivery. Now the minimum time required is 4 working days (Mon-Fri), so if they order on a Monday the minimum day they should be able to order for is Friday.

I thought I had it working correctly, however it is just been pointed out to me that they were able to select today as the delivery date, I inspected the page and seen that the minimum date was set to 2019-07-34. How can I fix this? I had just assumed that it would know how many days were in each month, mistake on my part.

This is the input for it:

```js
var today = new Date(); // current date/time 
var dd = today.getDay();
var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
var date = today.getDate();

if (dd < 10) {
    dd = '0' + dd
}

if (mm < 10) {
    mm = '0' + mm
}

if (dd == "03" || dd == "04" || dd == "05" || dd == "06") {
    dd = today.getDate() + 5;

    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);

} else if (date == "25" && mm == "12") {
    dd = today.getDate() + 5;
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);

} else if (date == "26" && mm == "12") {
    dd = today.getDate() + 4;
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);

} else if (date == "24" && mm == "12") {
    dd = today.getDate() + 5;
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);

} else if (date == "21" && mm == "12") {
    dd = today.getDate() + 6;
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);

} else if (date == "27" && mm == "12") {
    dd = today.getDate() + 6;
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);

} else if (date == "28" && mm == "12") {
    dd = today.getDate() + 5;
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);

} else if (date == "29" && mm == "12") {
    dd = today.getDate() + 5;
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);

} else if (date == "30" && mm == "12") {
    dd = today.getDate() + 5;
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);

} else if (date == "31" && mm == "12") {
    dd = today.getDate() + 5;
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);

} else if (date == "01" && mm == "01") {
    dd = today.getDate() + 6;
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);

} else {
    dd = today.getDate() + 4;
    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);
}
```

```html
<p>What date is this required for?</p>
<p>Please note, we need 4 days clear notice(Monday-Friday)</p>
<input id="datefield" name="date" type='date' required onkeydown="return false" min='2019-05-10'></input>
```

Not sure where I have gone wrong with this so any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really should simplify your code to handle the (not-so-uncommon) edge cases in fewer lines using Javascript's [`Date` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date), so that you don't end up adding days to your date's string representation and producing a non-existent date.

```js
var leadTime = 4; // working days required
var min = new Date(); // today's date
min.setDate(min.getDate() + leadTime); // set date to today + lead time
while (min.getDay() == 0 || min.getDay() == 6) // while the minimum day falls on a Saturday or Sunday....
  min.setDate(min.getDate() + 1); // add a full day to the originally-calculated date
document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", min.getFullYear() + "-" + ("0" + (min.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + min.getDate()).slice(-2)); // format date with leading zeroes for month and date numbers < 10
```

```html
<p>What date is this required for?</p>
<p>Please note, we need 4 days clear notice(Monday-Friday)</p>
<input id="datefield" name="date" type='date' required onkeydown="return false" min='2019-05-10'></input>
```

Comment: just curious, why would you prefer `getTime()` over `getDate()`?

Comment: @JohnnyAW a great question - it was what came to mind the fastest. You make a good implicit point that `getDate()` and `setDate()` would be way more readable - I've updated my answer to reflect this fact.

Comment: Thank you so much, works exactly how I want it to and I have a much better understanding now so thank you for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is here:

```
if (dd == "03" || dd == "04" || dd == "05" || dd == "06") {
    dd = today.getDate() + 5;

    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }
    today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;
    document.getElementById("datefield").setAttribute("min", today);
}
```

imagine `today.getDate()` will return `31` and you add `5` to it and then you put it together into a string `yyyy+'-'+mm+'-'+dd` you will end up with `36` for the day.

btw. you are doing it way too complicated. You could simplify your code doing this:

```
var today = new Date();
today.setDate(today.getDate() + 4);
while(today.getDay() === 0 || today.getDay() === 6) {
    today.setDate(today.getDate() + 1);
}
```

you simply add 4 days to the date and then add 1 day until you hit a working day.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Makes a lot more sense now